# Ubuntu 16.04 & 2016 Razer Blade 14" Display Issues

Tags: nvidia, uefi, display, suspend, display-resolution

For starters, I am quite new to Ubuntu. I had to do what to me seemed like a fair amount of work to get Ubuntu to work on my system. As of right now, it is working seemingly fine. There are a few remaining issues, but the only ones that irk me are related to display. I know everyone will want more information, and I'm happy to supply once I know what you'll want to see. But for starters:

Razer Blade 2016 14"

Dual-Booted w/ Windows 10

UEFI Secure Boot is still on my Bios

I am using the newest version of Nouveau Drivers

So the remaining problems are that I cannot change resolution size, nor can I suspend my laptop. I have attempted to install both Nvidia 364 and 367 - both led to black screens and one time to a login loop. When I did those, I believe I had also uninstalled my desktop and reinstalled it on someones advice. The resolution is quite annoying at this high of a resolution, as some things wont scale manually and I can barely see them. And suspend would be nice.

My fear is that I use Linux for work right now and can't have it crap out on me if I attempt to sort this out. I've been contemplating trying Bumblebee. My main concern is that I might be damaging my video card or my integrated graphics. I also understand from forums about this computer and linux on Razers website that battery is crap without sorting out driver issues, but I have yet to need to be mobile with this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For your battery life, have a look at the [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) and Powertop packages. Simply installing tlp gave me a couple hours battery life back and powertop is nice for monitoring. Mine also still doesn't suspend properly when I close the lid and I've been scouring the net trying everything, would be perfect if this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got linux mint 18(beta) with cinnamon to work on my razer blade 2016.
It works fine except for suspend. I can watch youtube/twitch for more than 3 hours without changing any settings.

AFAIK, people have not figured out a perfect soln for the suspend. Personally, I set my laptop to do nothing when lid closed. As for the nvidia driver, since I use linux for work, I am happy with the integrated graphics card. Also, from what I know, even for those who kinda get their nvidia card to work, there is some tearing and lagging when they watch videos.

I think we need to just wait for a perfect out-of-the-box soln.

Currently I am waiting for the new 4.7 kernel update since I think they fixed a bunch in 4.6

Great, 11 hours ago they just announced the official release of linux mint 18. I will try it.

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question...

Comment: Yeah, I mean, I'm hoping that my computer is running on integrated graphics but running lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' yields a result showing that no driver is in use on the skylake processor. So I think that the Nvidia card running Nouveau out of the box is the standard graphical support. Thats what concerns me. I went at a solution all of yesterday and could not get any combination of Nvidia drivers to play nice and once again fell back to Nouveau.

Comment: I'm running Mint 18.1 on my 2016 Blade and honestly, it's driving me up the wall. The lid closed thing is annoying, but the nVidia drivers are just next level frustrating. I basically have to chose between terrible screen tearing using the card, or the inability to shut down with the Intel graphics drivers. I had a good session trying to fix everything yesterday and now it's just f***ed. Drivers just don't work at all, PRIME has stopped working, I've tried everything to sort it but I think I'm looking at a full reinstall. Just don't think I want to go with Mint Cinnamon anymore.